# XLST Namespace URI included in XML element name

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, transform

so i have my namespace declared in the stylesheet like this

```
<xmlns:address="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"
```

below is my whole XSLT transform template

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:address="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="address">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="success"/>
<xsl:template match="paging"/>
<xsl:template match="orders">
    <xsl:element name="Items" >
        <xsl:for-each select="order">
            <xsl:element name="item">
                <xsl:element name="entity_id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="order_no"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="grand_total">
                    <xsl:value-of select="total"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="shipping_amount">
                    <xsl:value-of select="shipping"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="state">
                    <xsl:value-of select="status"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="created_at">
                    <xsl:value-of select="created"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:for-each select="client">
                    <address:customer_id>
                        <xsl:value-of select="client_id"/>
                    </address:customer_id>
                    <xsl:element name="address:firstname">
                        <xsl:value-of select="first_name"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="address:lastname">
                        <xsl:value-of select="last_name"/>
                    </xsl:element>  
                    <xsl:element name="address:company">
                        <xsl:value-of select="company"/>
                    </xsl:element>  
                    <xsl:element name="address:street">
                        <xsl:value-of select="street"/>
                    </xsl:element> 
                    <xsl:element name="address:city">
                        <xsl:value-of select="city"/>
                    </xsl:element>  
                    <xsl:element name="address:telephone">
                        <xsl:value-of select="phone"/>
                    </xsl:element>  
                    <xsl:element name="address:email">
                        <xsl:value-of select="email"/>
                    </xsl:element>  
                    <xsl:element name="address:region">
                        <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="items">
                    <xsl:for-each select="item">
                        <xsl:element name="product_name">
                            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="product_id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="product_id"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="price">
                            <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="item_id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="item_id"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="tax">
                            <xsl:value-of select="tax"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="qty">
                            <xsl:value-of select="qty"/>
                        </xsl:element>                            
                    </xsl:for-each>                        
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

what my intention is to create namespaced nodes like this `<address:lastname>` but what I get in the result is `<address:firstname xmlns:address="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">` I'm pretty new to XSLT so not really sure what's the problem saw a couple of posts that mention excluding namespace prefixes option that doesn't work either

Comment: Not sure what you expect. You cannot use a prefix without binding it to a nemespace, so the result you report is correct.

Comment: is there any way I can do it so it doesn't?

Comment: First of all, consider to use literal result elements (e.g. `<address:firstname>...</address:firstname>`) instead of `xsl:element` which would only be needed if you want to compute element names. And of course if you want the root element to declare and have the prefix then you need to make sure you do not use `exclude-result-prefixes="address"`.

Comment: Yes, I've tried all those combinations as well, `xmlns:address="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"` still follows, just if I don't remove that then PHP code that needs it as `<address:firstname>` format, won't recognize it at all as a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, the result you report is correct:  a well-formed XML document cannot use a prefix without binding it to a namespace. If your target application cannot handle this, then it is not conforming to the XML specifications.

However, you can try moving the namespace declaration to your root element instead of having it repeated on every `address::*` element. Instead of:

```
<xsl:element name="Items" >
```

use:

```
<Items xmlns:address="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
```

and remove same namespace declaration from your `xsl:stylesheet` start tag. This should result in a document structured like:

```
<Items xmlns:address="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <item>
    <entity_id/>
    <grand_total/>
    <shipping_amount/>
    <state/>
    <created_at/>
    <address:customer_id/>
    <address:firstname/>
    <address:lastname/>
    <address:company/>
    <address:street/>
    <address:city/>
    <address:telephone/>
    <address:email/>
    <address:region/>
  </item>
</Items>
```

which hopefully your target application may handle better than your (semantically identical) current result.

---

As noted in the comments, you can simplify your stylesheet by replacing all the other `xsl:element` instructions with literal result elements too.

Comment: I'm not sure this does the trick `<xsl:element name="Items" xmlns:address="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">` I've tried this solution as well, and also did the replacement with literal elements

Comment: Oh sorry, now it worked when i changed to this `<Items xmlns:address="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"` thanks for the help